# Building a modelling app in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I hope this question isn't too vague for SO..

I want to build a typical designer/modeller app in WPF. So, you have a main initially blank canvas area, and you drag items onto that from the toolbox to build up a model of something. Once you've dragged items into the canvas from the toolbox, you then need to be able to bring up a bunch of properties etc.. Kind of like Visio, or the workflow designer in visual studio.

Before I set about building this from scratch, I was wondering if there are any tools/frameworks/libraies that will help me achieve this with minimal work. It seems to me to be a common use case so I was thinking that there should be something to help. I actually looked at rehosting the workflow designer because that has a lot of what I want to do, but since I'm not in any way modelling workflows I figured that wouldn't be the best way forwards.

Is there anything that provides a starting point for this, or is it a case of jumping in and getting started from scratch?

Comment: I've seen Go recommended http://www.nwoods.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kind of added value you want. I would suggest looking at [YFiles](http://www.yworks.com/en/products_yfiles_dotnetplatform_about.html), it has some interresting tools regarding Diagrams. Telerik and Syncfusion have good WPF controls libraries  but I'm not sure they have interresting stuffs regarding designer/modeller material.

Comment: Telerik have a new diagramming control that looks promising http://www.telerik.com/products/wpf/diagrams.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look into that, it looks interresting !

Comment: Thanks for the Telerik links - those diagramming demos look amazing, and might well do what I want.